# Werewolf horror novel where the werewolf attacks people in cars and eats a child

Tags: story-identification, novel, werewolf

The story begins with a werewolf attacking a couple I think in car. In one particular scene the werewolf is attacking a family in their RV and eats the child.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking a good question to see if they help you recall any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: Was the werewolf/monster the protagonist or was the family?

Answer (score -1):

This is a long shot but could it be Clive Barker's [*Rawhead Rex*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2355227.Rawhead_Rex) (1976)? Not a werewolf but a bestial god/monster.

> Rawhead it was called because its head was huge and raw like meat. It was the last of a line of kings dating from before civilization, before Christ, when England was forest all over... and the home of unspeakable horror. The most famous and powerful story came from Clive Barker's Books of Blood is here unforgettably illustrated. The incomparable talent of Les Edwards brings ancient evil to life.

Comment: I've edited out your questions as they belong in a comment ___not___ in an answer and posted them as a comment for you. I also tried to flesh the answer out a bit more by adding a basic description in. You can further flesh this out by explaining ___how___ it matches the OP's description, see [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/58193) for some pointers.